# Editing excel with npoi breaks buttom with macro

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have excel template that I copy and populate using npoi. I take a copy of original. This works fine but after I put set cell values the button that has macros breaks
Is there something that can be done?

I originally crated new excel and transfered the content and of course this didn't bring macro so I switched to copy. This worked on first step but now adding the cell value is problem. Values come to excel nicely. Values are just simple texts or numbers.

```
// Paramerters
string filename_org = "Excel_template.xlsm";

// Template file
string server_folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
string file_path_org = server_folder + "\\temp\\" + filename_org;


// New File ****************************************************************
string filename_new = "Report_for_" + root.getProperty( "name", "" ) + "_" + pval.Replace("-", "_").Replace(":", "_") + ".xlsm";
string file_path_new = server_folder + "\\temp\\" + filename_new;
// Copy file here **********************************************************
System.IO.File.Copy(file_path_org, file_path_new, true);

FileStream fs;
try {
    fs = new FileStream(file_path_new, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
} catch( Exception e) {
    return inn.newError("Opening the Excel Template File FAILED: " + e.Message);
}
CCO.Utilities.WriteDebug("Excel_Report", "file_Open");
if (fs != null) { 
    // WORKBOOK ****************************************************************
    IWorkbook xssWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    fs.Close();
    // WORKSHEET
    ISheet sheet = xssWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
    // UPDATE CELL VALUES ******************************************************
     //LOTS OF THESE HERE
    sheet.GetRow(9).GetCell(1).SetCellValue( root.getProperty( "name", "" ) );
   

    // Save new result file ****************************************************
    using (var fs2 = new FileStream(file_path_new, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        xssWorkbook.Write(fs2,false);
        fs2.Close();
    }
}
CCO.Utilities.WriteDebug("Excel_REPORT", "Properties added");

//Add file to vault ************************************************************
Item file = inn.newItem("File","add");
file.setProperty("filename", filename_new);
file.attachPhysicalFile(file_path_new);
Item returnItem = file.apply();
returnItem.setProperty("errors",errorMessage);  
// Delete copied File
File.Delete(file_path_new);

return returnItem;
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the some code.